# How to trigger router error handler instead of default error handler in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

My express app uses the default JSON body parser:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Further down the `app.js` file I have my own router for building REST API routes:

```
var api = require('./routes/api/index');
...
app.use('/api', api);
```

This router has an error handler, among other things:

```
router.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  debugger;
  res.status(err.code ? getParseErrorStatus(err.code) : res.status || 500).send({
    error: err.message
  });
});
```

Whenever the bodyParser throws an error while parsing the request body, I get my generic express error handler called:

```
// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    debugger;
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}
```

This holds true even for calls to `/api/*` URLs that are caught by the API router.

Instead of always calling the generic error handler, how can I make JSON parsing errors (caught by middleware up in the chain) call the error handler I've defined in the API router, if the URL is an API URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error handlers are called at the same router stack level. Since the `bodyParser.json()` is executed at the main/root/app layer, it will look for the first error handler at the main/root/app layer.

So if you want to handle API body parsing errors, you will have to move your `bodyParser.json()` middleware to each of your routes/routers that require body parsing.